# How do you gracefully parse a BadRequest ProblemDetails and access the errors on the client?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

Here is a example where MVC ModelState is invalid and the MVC returns a 400 response

[image]

I am interested in using the "errors" property for the UI. But when deserialized to a ProblemDetails this info is putted in the Extension dictionary.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.problemdetails?view=aspnetcore-7.0

I am looking for a MS extension or some github/nuget code, that would give me a proper API to access this.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.validationproblemdetails?view=aspnetcore-7.0 <-- that's the actual class used for validation errors.

Comment: ahh your are right, I wasn't using this in my controller in the ProducesResponseType attribute. So the Open API contract was not complete. Thanks a lot.